# Model in parent scope prevents model in subprocess scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing

So here's the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to train a model in a multiprocessing `Process`, but when a model already exist in the parent scope, the process will freeze at the initialization of the `Embedding` layer.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Embedding
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf


def make_model(vecs, weights=None):
    inp = Input((5,))
    embd = Embedding(len(vecs), 50, weights=[vecs], trainable=False)(inp)
    out = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(embd)
    model = Model(inp, out)
    model.compile(Adam(0.001), 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def f(vecs, conn):
    model = make_model(vecs)
    conn.send('done')
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vecs = np.random.random((100000, 50))
    model1 = make_model(vecs)

    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(vecs, child_conn), daemon=True)
    p.start()

    print('starting model two')
    print(parent_conn.recv())
    print('completed')
```

When this script is run as it's currently written, it will never print the 'completed' message. If, however, I comment out the line `model1 = make_model(vecs)` then it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Karas is really nice and user friendly and pretty awesome. But ... it does a lot of "magic" that can make it hard to work with if you want to do anything "non-standard".

When you fork the child process from the parent process it copies keras' state, which holds some assumptions that are true for the original process but not the child. You could go digging in the code to figure out what those assumptions are.

Notice that if you move `model1 = make_model(vecs)` after `p.start()` then everything works. The reason is that the child process copies keras in its "clean" state (before anything has been run). This state is modified in the child process but that doesn't affect the parent process.

An even better fix is to move all the keras imports into your target function and never import keras in the parent process, that way you can safely launch as many children as you want.

Comment: The problem is that it must be this way; this is for a server and the active models need to be loaded into the parent process.

Comment: @haaf The issue is that keras models are stateful objects that cannot be shared between processes. Unfortunately keras was not designed with multiprocessing or distributed processing in mind.